# Redefine include path C++

Tags: c++, g++

I have a file included, not within the project root - let's say "*root/libs/lib.h*". Now, this file itself is including several (lots of actually) files. And, they are all in another subdirectory, lets say "*root/libs/includes*". Now, I have to write this in the *lib.h*:

```
#include "includes/file1.c"
#include "includes/file2.c"
/*and so on*/
#include "includes/file20.c"
```

Now, wouldn't it be easier, and more flexible, if i could change actual include path?

```
#set_include_path "includes";
#include "file1.c"
/* ... */
#include "file20.c"
#set_include_path "..";   //returning to original folder
```

I believe this is compiler dependent feature, so for replies, mention the compiler too. I'm using G++ myself.

Comment: Are you asking whether there are compilers that support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `-I` command line argument:

```
g++ -Iincludes somefile.cpp ...
```

For more information, please see [the reference](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options).

Comment: Well, I don't want to pass my included files by parameter... I want to keep them in the file that includes them.

Comment: @TomášZato In that case there's nothing you can do. It's either the `-I` option or nothing at all.